# Is asking about software to work with ebooks ontopic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I want to ask a question about software for transforming ebooks.
Basically I am looking for software that detects which characters Point of View,
the story is from, and reorders the chapters so that you can read on character continuously.
This is a surpisingly commonly recommended technique for reading epic fantasy books that have tens of thousands of pages and hundreds of characters.

Anyway, would such a question (with more detail, of course) be on topic here?

however this sounds like a software rec question which is not allowed on most SE sites.

Comment: This seems on-topic to me, because this is not a programming or code-related site. Tool recommendations are fine here. That said, I have no idea what tools might help you.

Comment: Sounds fine to me. I'd be interested in hearing about anything like that out there. Sounds like a great idea for a tool, but I don't know how feasible it would be without having that information marked up in the book in some way. (Chapters named for characters, as in Game of Thrones, would be fairly straightforward though).

Comment: I think it would be quiet easy, (I've been considering programming one myself). First nondictionary word would be indicative of first name mentioned. Cross refference for number of occurances. Anyway, I will create a proper question for this soon

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers on this site that involve the transformation of ebooks from one format into another.

[Your question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1018/60) which involves just another transformation seems right on target to me. Several of the answers involve some code, and as long as this is directly ebook related it is more on topic here than it would be on StackOverflow, where issues that are better handled on SE sites for a specific subject, are going to be closed as belonging on that other site.